# SVG as background-image?

Tags: html, svg

I have an SVG file place in solution and I have a master page where I want to put that SVG as a background image. I have tried with:

```
html { background-image: url("../Images/MainBackground.svg"); }
```

But it does't work; the SVG doesn't appear at all.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the svg file to the question.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should set background on "body" and not on "html".

BTW: that will not work with internet explorer.

EDIT:

Try this on you CSS

```
background-image: url(your-file.svg);
-o-background-size: 100% 100%;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but still it doesn't work even i have tested with IE and Firefox both. So can you please give me some code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for your support basically the problem is with my IIS. I need to add a new mime type for .svg.